# Multiple instances of global data when linking into multiple projects

Tags: c++, linker, extern

I have a Visual C++ solution, which consists out of 3 projects.

One of these projects, project "A" is used by both other projects and it has some global data which should always be the same.

However when I link project A into both other projects it seems that two instances of project A are working on different data.

Can this be the case and how can I set up the linking process to prevent this from happending?

--- Update to make things more clear

```
- Project 1 -

main () {
  init();
  test();
}

- Project 2 -

test () {
  cout << get_data();
}

- Project A -

int data;

init() {
  data = 123;
}

get_data() {
  return data;
}
```

---

As you can see in this exaple I am initializeing the data of project A in the first project and I am accessing it from the second project. My observation is that the data is not initialized when the acces from the second project takes place.

Both projects A and 2 are linked statically into project 1 so the output is a single executable.

Comment: I think you need to be more explicit here: You indicate below that Project A is a static library, Is it true that project B and C are two different programs that generate two different executable files (thus two processes? If not please explain the nature of projects B and C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symbols from project A in the static library are linked into both project 1 and project 2, separately. Getting them merged involves compiler-specific mechanisms.

Basically, you must make project 2 re-export project A's symbols, and have project 1 import those instead of importing project A directly.

If you can't do that (e.g. because you don't have control over either project 1 or 2), you must write workarounds inside project A. One option (the easiest usually) is to convert project A to a dynamic library. Then both project 1 and 2 load the same instance of project A and the data is shared.

Another option is to change project A so that it doesn't have a global variable, but instead registers a process-global data item that contains the data you want; for example, you could abuse the local atom table[1] to store a pointer to dynamic memory.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Integer_Atoms

Answer (score 2):

A global resides in a single place in a process's memory space. If you have two processes that share a module, they'll each have separate variable, yes.

You'll need to use IPC to share data between processes.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear about that. I do not use a DLL but a static library instead. I guess I should use something like the "extern" keyword - however I am not sure how to use it in my context.

Comment: @Constantin my answer still remains. If there are 2 different processes, there will be 2 different variables.

Comment: Sure, however, I have just one process as the libary is linked statically into the other projects. So what I get is one executable and such just one process...

Comment: @Constantin reduce the code as much as you can and post it in the question. Then show us how you compile/link and how you run.